# Attempt at Blender with a lot of help from ChatGPT could not complete the task, which should be straight forward

Tags: modeling, python, scripting

I am trying to build an object model on 3D. It should consist of the intersection of the surfaces of a cone and a square pyramid. Once the intersection object is built the cone and pyramid should disappear and only the "intersection" should be rotated so that from one direction it looks like a square and from the other it looks like a circle. The following link should visually describe the model
https://youtu.be/KYMYshbhKcw?si=bM_eIHkkNITFbMdh
Obviously there is more I might like to do, but I cannot even complete the above described task. The latest code is below

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import math

def create_objects():
    # Clear existing objects
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='MESH')
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

    # Create cone
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add(vertices=32, radius1=1, depth=3, location=(0, 0, 1))
    cone = bpy.context.active_object

    # Create square pyramid
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add(vertices=4, radius1=1, depth=3, location=(0, 0, -1))
    pyramid = bpy.context.active_object

    # Invert only the pyramid
    pyramid.rotation_euler = (0, math.pi, 0)  # Rotate 180 degrees around Y axis

    # Create boolean intersection
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    cone.select_set(True)
    pyramid.select_set(True)

    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = cone
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BOOLEAN')
    bool_modifier = cone.modifiers.new(name="Boolean", type='BOOLEAN')
    bool_modifier.operation = 'INTERSECT'
    bool_modifier.use_self = True
    bool_modifier.use_self_location = True
    bool_modifier.use_self_rotation = True

    # Apply boolean modifier
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply({"object": cone}, modifier="Boolean")

    # Adjust position of the cone (if needed)
    cone.location = (0, 0, 1)

    # Hide the original objects
    cone.hide_set(True)
    pyramid.hide_set(True)

    # Set up scene
    bpy.context.scene.frame_start = 1
    bpy.context.scene.frame_end = 1

# Run the function
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
create_objects()
```

I get errors. I would be very grateful for any assistance
Regards
Giorgio

Comment: Hello, FWIW you can copy/paste the errors that are written in the console back into the chatbox and ask chatGPT to fix them.

Comment: If you want to convince us GPT is bad, it seems you're in the wrong place, we already know that :D AI is good for repeatable problems, when the problems appeared multiple times in its learning dataset. But since Blender coding is rather niche, chatGPT struggles at Blender problems. It's even worse when you're good in Blender coding, because then your problems get harder and rarer and GPT turns out to be a huge waste of time. I made a thorough test once, and 9 out of 11 lines of AI generated script turned out to be wrong, with the heart of the problem not addressed by GPT…

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady. I wasn't trying to put GPT down. In other instances GPT has helped to write a geolocation script that converted a csv file to kml. I felt interested in the animation described. I had tried Geogebra unsuccessfully and I wasn't looking forward to doing a huge amount of learning, given that it is unlikely I would be doing much more work with Blender or similar packages

Comment: @Gorgious, thanks. Next time I will post the errors.

Comment: To be devil's advocate, the paid version of chatGPT is way better, according to the few people I know to develop addons using it. But...  Personally, I'm not gonna pay for that.

Answer (score 3):

```
bool_modifier.use_self_location = True
bool_modifier.use_self_rotation = True
```

These lines try to set non existing attributes. This is what the error message tells you:

> Python: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users-\Desktop\test.blend\Text", line 51, in    File
> "C:\Users-\Desktop\test.blend\Text", line 32, in create_objects
> AttributeError: 'BooleanModifier' object has no attribute
> 'use_self_location'

Boolean modifier simply doesn't have settings like that. Since the lines have no purpose, they can simply be deleted.

Both of these lines add a new boolean modifier to the same cone object:

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BOOLEAN')
bool_modifier = cone.modifiers.new(name="Boolean"
```

Since you want to change settings of the modifier and need only one boolean modifier, you should leave only the one assigned to the variable.

The next problem is that the object used by the boolean modifier is never selected, so you need to address that and set `modifier.object` to your pyramid.

The next issue is that the operator `bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply()` is not used correctly. Chat GPT tries to override the context and also does some random stuff there. At this point there is no need to override context, and we [see in the docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply) that `modifier` in `bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply()` should be a string:

> modifier (string, (optional, never None)) – Modifier, Name of the
> modifier to edit

So that should be the name - in your case `bool_modifier.name`.

The next issue is that both objects are hidden while the result of the boolean modifier is stored in one(the cone) so you probably don't want to hide it.

Chat GPT also randomly imports `bmesh` and `math` that are not used and for some reason feels like setting start and end frames that doesn't seem relevant here at all.

## How to actually solve the real problem here?

Chat GPT or at least the version you are using is clearly not ready for this yet. As we can clearly see - it simply doesn't work. The solution is to learn [Python](https://www.python.org/) and [Blender's Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html) yourself. Not an answer one likes to get, sure, but that's the actual solution. There are plenty of good resources in the links as well as tutorials on YouTube and elsewhere on the web. Blender Stack Exchange is also a very valuable resource, that may work a lot better when you have specific questions about specific issues. When you learn to use it, you can use it to achieve results like you want, but it seems at the moment, you cannot skip that learning part.

Comment: I tried to give you a positive vote, but I am not allowed at this stage. I am very grateful for the time and effort you devoted to my issue.
I have modified the code , but I am stuck at bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(), which I modified to
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply( bool_modifier.name), given that I used the following 
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BOOLEAN')
    bool_modifier = cone.modifiers.new(name='Boolean', type='BOOLEAN')
The err produced is 
 Calling operator "bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply" error, expected a string enum in ... Ta
G.A.
PS I need to read more or pay someone

Comment: bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier = bool_modifier.name)  See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp) about function arguments in Python, they can be positional when you just write them when calling a function like f(5, "banana") or keyword(named) like f(x = 5, y = "banana"). W3schools is awesome for learning as well.

Comment: I am glad to hear "When you learn to use it, you can use it to achieve results like you want,..." For that reason, I will embark on a learning expedition and only return to the task when I have assimilated the fundamentals, at least. I think I will attempts the task manually first and then programmatically.Thanks

Comment: Progress. Intersection built. Animation and scripting next. Thanks. I am sure I will need more assistance with specific hiccups. Is it best to use this question or start separate ones?

Comment: Love the last part of that answer  I'd like to mention the existence of [EasyBPY by Curtis Holt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybnapDe4-Ts). It doesn't replace learning py and bpy, but it does a good job of making things simpler to read and think for devs, and I reckon it makes it a nice stool to step on the train.